# Kendo UI Grid Format Date column

Tags: datetime, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to show a datetime column appropriately in my Kendo UI Grid. Date is being shown successfully, but not time. Here's a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vu79cLpe/) showing my scenario.

```
field: "Date",
title: "Date",
format: "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",
parseFormats: ["MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss"]
```

I have tried different alternatives with no success. Any thoughts on how to show the content as expected would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

Use template:

```
 {
    field: "Date"
    , title: "Date"
    , width: "100px"
    , template: "#=  (Date == null)? '' : kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MM/dd/yy') #"
 },
```

Comment: This prints the date, but without any time information at all. Completely the wrong answer.

Comment: This doesn't print the time with the date, update the format to correct.

Answer (score 2):

datatype you specified for date field is date type.it should be datetime as shown in the below

```
fields: {
    Id: { type: 'number' },
    FirstName: { type: 'string' },
    LastName : { type: 'string' },
    Date: { type: 'datetime' }
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks! PS: I will accept your answer in 5 mins

Comment: This doesn't work. It displays the full date, yes, but it doesn't parse it properly. It's just defaulting to printing the given string straight to the screen with no formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working based on your fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kh9tk5fm/1/). I modified the object definition slightly and kept the "date" data type:

```
{
    field       : "Date",
    title       : "Date",
    format      : "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",
    parseFormats: ["MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss"],
    filterable: {
        ui: "datetimepicker"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you kryptonkal, but I don't see the time correctly in your jsfiddle. It says 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score -1):

columns.Bound(date=> date.START_DATE).Title("Start Date").Format("{0:MM dd, yyyy}");